# Overlapping call durations

Tags: sql, sql-server, overlap

Is there a way to work out if a call overlaps another call already in progress.

For example I have a call that comes in at `10:00` and ends at `10:05`.

Second call comes in at `10:02` and ends at `10:06` so is overlapping the first calls, how could I show this in a sql query? I have a few thousand calls to compare.

Table I have uses `CallID, TimeAns, TimeFin`

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server find overlaping date ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087348/sql-server-find-overlaping-date-ranges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is non-inclusive query:

```
SELECT * FROM myCalls t1
INNER JOIN myCalls t2 on t2.CallID != t1.CallID 
    AND t1.TimeAns < t2.TimeFin
    AND t1.TimeFin >  t2.TimeAns
```

This query will return 2 rows for each overlap. if you want to have just one row per overlap this will do it:

```
SELECT * FROM myCalls t1
INNER JOIN myCalls t2 on t2.CallID > t1.CallID 
    AND t1.TimeAns < t2.TimeFin
    AND t1.TimeFin >  t2.TimeAns
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, ive accepted this answer as this is the one I tested and is now working and is the most logical to me, although I know some of the other queries as similar so probably do the same job

Answer (score 0):

Two calls overlap when start or end of call 1 is between start and end of call 2. (No matter, which of the two calls you call "call 1" and which "call 2".)

```
WHERE 
(
  call1.start BETWEEN call2.start AND call2.end
  OR
  call1.end BETWEEN call2.start AND call2.end
)
```

EDIT: And make your mind up, if you consider two calls where one ends at the same time as the other starts overlapping or not. The BETWEEN clause does. So if you don't want this, replace this by `(call1.start > call2.start AND call1.start < call2.end)`.

EDIT: To find all overlapping call combinations:

```
select * 
from calls
join calls other 
  on other.callid < calls.callid and 
  (
    (calls.timeans > other.timeans and calls.timeans < other.timefin)
    or
    (calls.timefin > other.timeans and calls.timeans < other.timefin)
  )
;
```

Comment: I have a few thousand calls id need to compare sorry I should have mentioned this isn't just for 2 calls

Comment: So describe your desired results. Do you have one call you want to know for whether it overlaps with any other? Or do you want to select all overlapping call combinations in your table? (The condition stays the same, by the way; you always compare two calls at a time.)

Comment: I want to compare a whole table of calls to see how many calls overlap

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this edit, it still looks like it just compares 2 calls, I know I have to compare 2 at a time but how do I do the rest of the calls.

Comment: You take one record from calls, then you look for another record in calls that overlaps (so you loop through the table and compare two calls at a time). Then you take the next record from calls and loop again through the other calls, etc. This is what the query does. I use `other.callid < calls.callid` in order not to get duplicates (a overlaps with b and b overlaps with a). Okay?

Answer (score 0):

Join on the same table where the two calls overlap:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
JOIN TABLE t2 on t2.CallID != TABLE.CallID and 
    (CallID.TimeFin BETWEEN t2.TimeAns AND t2.TimeFin
    OR CallID.TimeAns BETWEEN t2.TimeAns AND t2.TimeFin)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Refer  [Working ORACLE Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4989d8/1):
- Refer  [Working SQL SERVER Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25df7/1):

The Query should help you:

```
SELECT A.callID ,
A.startTime OVERLAPPING_START_TIME, 
A.endTime OVERLAPPING_END_TIME
    FROM phoneCall A 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         phoneCall B 
   ON A.callID != B.callID
WHERE
      ((B.startTime) BETWEEN (A.STARTTIME) AND (A.endTime ))
OR 
      ((B.endTime ) BETWEEN (A.STARTTIME) AND (A.endTime ))
```

Comment: @user3691566: REFER : Fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25df7/1 for SQL Server