# how to get values based on mutiple date combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, overlap

i have to retrieve interest values for a statement billing cycle and these interest values will be different from day to day.
to be more clear:

I have a table [APPLICABLEINTEREST] where there is column [interest].This [interest] value varies depends on two other columns [EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] and [EFFECTIVETODATE].

lets take an example:

```
[interest] =10% [EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] = sep 1st 2014 [EFFECTIVETODATE] = sep 15th 2014.

[interest] = 20% [EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] = sep 16th 2014 [EFFECTIVETODATE] = sep 30th 2014

[interest] = 30% [EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] = oct 1st 2014 [EFFECTIVETODATE] = null (this means for remaining dates)
```

Now i have to retrieve these values for a statement period.

for ex1: if my statement period is between sep 1st and sep 30th,i have to retrieve both 10% and 20%

for ex2: if my statement period is between sep17th and oct 15th ,i have to retrieve both 20% and 30%

iam trying the following code:

```
 declare @Fromdate date='2014-08-10'
 declare @Todate date='2014-09-14'

select [iinterest] from APPLICABLEINTEREST where (EFFECTIVEFROMDATE >=@Fromdate and EFFECTIVETODATE<=@Todate)
  Or
 (EFFECTIVEFROMDATE <=@Fromdate and EFFECTIVETODATE<=@Todate)
 Or
 (EFFECTIVEFROMDATE <=@Fromdate and EFFECTIVETODATE>=@Todate)
 Or
 (EFFECTIVEFROMDATE >=@Fromdate and EFFECTIVETODATE>=@Todate)
 Or
 (EFFECTIVEFROMDATE >=@Fromdate and EFFECTIVETODATE<=@Todate)
```

but this is not working as it doesn't suit all the conditions.

any help ? thanks in advance

Edit:

```
declare @Fromdate date='2014-09-01'
declare @Todate date='2014-10-30'

select DAILYAPPLICABLEINTERESTRATE from LOCAPPLICABLEINTEREST where
@Fromdate between EFFECTIVEFROMDATE and EFFECTIVETODATE or @Todate between EFFECTIVEFROMDATE and EFFECTIVETODATE
```

This skips when i have interest rates 3 which are

sep1st to sep 15 as .75
  sep16 to oct1 as .95
  oct 2nd to oct 30 as .99

for these values the above query returns .75 and .99(it skips .95 eventhough it falss between sep01 and oct 30)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlapping call durations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722694/overlapping-call-durations)

Comment: try reversing the relationship, if @ Fromdate between EFFECTIVEFROMDATE  and EFFECTIVETODATE or @ Todate between EFFECTIVEFROMDATE  and EFFECTIVETODATE

Comment: @Used_By_Already this skips one condition.

Comment: @Used_By_Already edited the question.Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's basics of what I'd do:

```
create table APPLICABLEINTEREST (iinterest decimal, EFFECTIVEFROMDATE date,EFFECTIVETODATE date)
insert into APPLICABLEINTEREST
values 
(10, '2014-09-1', '2014-09-15')
, (20, '2014-09-16', '2014-09-30')
, (30, '2014-10-1', '9999-12-31')

create table DATES (D_DATE date)
go

-- filling sample dates
with xDAYS as (
    SELECT TOP (2000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects
)
insert into DATES
select D_DATE from (select CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n, '2013-12-30')) as D_DATE from xDAYS) d
ORDER BY D_DATE

declare @Fromdate date='2014-09-10'
declare @Todate date='2014-10-14'

select EFFECTIVEFROMDATE, EFFECTIVETODATE, iinterest, count(*) as number_of_days from APPLICABLEINTEREST a
inner join DATES d on d.D_DATE between EFFECTIVEFROMDATE and EFFECTIVETODATE
where d.D_DATE between @Fromdate and @Todate
group by EFFECTIVEFROMDATE, EFFECTIVETODATE, iinterest
```

That is:

- have a "calendar" table (`DATES`) (for real worlds interest calculation will need working days flags etc)
- join it to interest rate table (`APPLICABLEINTEREST`)

**EDIT :**

Alternatively, for very basic selection of rates within period:

```
select iinterest from APPLICABLEINTEREST 
 where @Todate >= EFFECTIVEFROMDATE and @Fromdate < EFFECTIVETODATE
```

Comment: Proposed "Dates" table based on experience, you anyway end up needing one for such application/calculation + it makes getting the query right easier :-). For simple query retrieving applicable rates see my alternate answer below EDIT.